# How to know the file which i am trying to copy might take more than 15mins or long time to copy in AS400?

Tags: ibm-midrange, ibm-ifs

I am trying to copy a physical file to a stream file and than to excel sheet, generally to copy a file more than 5000 records it is taking around 5mins to do the process. I want to submit this copying process in batch, now the problem is how can i tell the program to submit the process in batch if it takes long time to copy.

Comment: That's a long time for not too many records. You could probably speed it up by generating the Excel file directly from the data in the physical file (for example, by using Python).

Comment: Normally, if a task *might* take a long time, then you should simply assume that it *will* take a long time, and just submit it to batch. Don't bother trying to figure out a scheme for "sometimes we'll submit it and sometimes not". Just submit it. Every time.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to familiarize yourself with the [SBMJOB](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/cl/sbmjob.htm) command. This will run a program in a new non-interactive job rather than on your interactive screen. It is often useful to write a short CL program to call SBMJOB so that you have a record of what parameters you want to send it.  You can then just `CALL` the CL program from the command line.